# Quarterly NPS dashboard

Tags: microsoft-excel, dashboard

Our survey responses are dumped into one file which is updated daily.  From this we can calculate an NPS over any period.  I want to create a dashboard workbook that points to this base file and displays the NPS per quarter, per year.

[Sample survey data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UElLp.png)

An NPS is calculated like this: find the percentage of responses that are 9 or 10, and subtract the percentage of responses that are less than 7.  In this sample, 50% of responses are 9 or 10, 33.33% are less than 7, so the NPS is 16.67.

And I want to do this by quarter.  Ideally I need to do it without helper columns as I'd like it to be one cell pulling the calc from the base sheet and representing it into a chart.  But there are too many different types of selections involved here and I can't get them straight.

I know I need to use YEAR() and MONTH() on the AddDate to get those selections, and I know I can ROUNDUP(MONTH()/3,0) to get the quarter for each date.  COUNTIF() won't take YEAR() or MONTH() as inputs.  I've tried using something like this SUMPRODUCT() as a basis (just to get the scores greater than 8):

=SUMPRODUCT(--(ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2:A100)/3,0)=1)*(YEAR(A2:A100)=2018)*(B2:B100>8),B18:B10016)

but this sums the results rather than counting them, and I can't figure out how to wrap it in a count.

At this point, I don't know if I'm even on the right track.  Maybe there's something other than SUMPRODUCT() that I should be using here.  If the data were formatted differently - if it already noted the year and month as values I could grab directly - I could do this, but I have to use the data as it currently stands.

Any pointers gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you think that Promoters are worth 1, Passives are 0 and Detractors are -1 you can then average these individual scores to get your NPS.

In your example provided you effectively substitute in -1, 0, 1, -1, 1, 1 which when averaged gives 16.67%

This method of calculating averages can be subbed in to an array formula that looks something like:

```
=AVERAGE(IF(YEAR(A2:A100)=2019,IF(ROUNDUP(MONTH(A2:A100)/3,0)=1,IF(B2:B100>8,1,IF(B2:B100>6,0,-1)))))
```

Then press Ctrl, Shift + Enter to calculate it as an array